# How do i sum two query with each count and criteria in it

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this two query sql and i'm trying to do a sum of both 2 counts in the query together but when i try to do the `UNION ALL` but it kept prompt me to enter parameter for `CountOfTools_Number2`. All i wan is the `sum` of the two count and return me a value.

```
SELECT Count(Test.Tool_Number) AS CountOfTool_Number1
FROM Test INNER JOIN Test_Tool ON Test.Tool_Number = Test_Tool.Current_Tool
GROUP BY Test_Tool.Current_Test
HAVING (((Test_Tool.Current_Test) Like "*E1*"));
```

```
SELECT Count(Test.Tool_Number) AS CountOfTool_Number2
FROM Test_Tool, Test INNER JOIN Previous_Tool ON Test.Tool_Number = Previous_Tool.Previous_Tool
GROUP BY Test_Tool.Current_Test
HAVING (((Test_Tool.Current_Test) Like "*E1*"));
```

Comment: The field name is CountOfTool_Number2, not CountOfTools_Number2 - note the `s`. Does the second query open and correctly show data? I think the FROM syntax is wrong. Shouldn't the filter criteria be WHERE instead of HAVING and precede GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming your two example queries work, this should do the trick:

```
select 
    sum(CountOfTool_Number1) as CountOfTool
from (

    SELECT Count(Test.Tool_Number) AS CountOfTool_Number1
    FROM Test INNER JOIN Test_Tool ON Test.Tool_Number = Test_Tool.Current_Tool
    GROUP BY Test_Tool.Current_Test
    HAVING (((Test_Tool.Current_Test) Like "*E1*"))

    union all

    SELECT Count(Test.Tool_Number) AS CountOfTool_Number2
    FROM Test_Tool, Test INNER JOIN Previous_Tool ON Test.Tool_Number = Previous_Tool.Previous_Tool
    GROUP BY Test_Tool.Current_Test
    HAVING (((Test_Tool.Current_Test) Like "*E1*"))

    ) as q;
```

Comment: For this line
`select sum(CountofTool_Number1) as CountOfTool`
why do i not need to include `CountofTool_Number2` in the starting line

Comment: @CodingPastMidnight in a union query, the column names are taken from the first query only. Try running just the union query on it's own and you will see.

Comment: so if i were to do union next time, i just need to select the column name from the first query and it will automatically take into account of the second query?

Comment: @CodingPastMidnight correct, in fact you don't even need to set a column alias in the second query as the values in that column position will fall under the column name defined in the first query. Glad I was able to help!